# cockroachdb with spring webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cockroachdb

Does cockroachdb support spring reactive api?

I know none of the relational data base support reactive api as they are blocking calls.
is coachroach DB any different?

Comment: I'm not sure the question makes sense; it's more about the driver to the database - have you tried `R2DBC` for Postgres when working with CockroachDB?

Comment: yes, I know. I am in the discovery phase and new to the cockroach. Does R2DBC supports non-blocking or reactive API? I am trying to decide whether to use the spring reactive API or not with Cockroach DB. Last time when I used the reactive API, I have to drop it as I was using oracle database.

Comment: https://r2dbc.io/ Spring support & Postgres protocol.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, CockroachDB supports Spring reactive API. Under the hood, CockroachDB relies on PostgreSQL Java drivers to connect to applications. So, if there is a Java driver that works with Spring reactive and Postgres, it will work with CockroachDB too.